# Helix3dToolkit Grouping Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

Is it possible to group helix3d objects, and then adding them into a `HelixViewport3D` together. (And be able to remove together as well).

This can actually be done with `BillboardTextVisual3D` objects, by using a single `BillboardTextGroupVisual3D` object.

But I couldn't yet find something similar to group other generic objects (`BoxVisual3D`, `RectangleVisual3D`, etc.)

I found two classes, `Model3DGroup` and `Visul3DCollection`, which looked promising, but couldn't be used for my purpose.

My questions are:

1. Can this be done?
2. If it can be done, how?